# Asp.net datalist RepeatDirection.Vertical shows horizontal? set repeatcolumns in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, datalist

i have a datalist in my aspx like this:

```
<asp:DataList 
     ID="dlSubs" 
     runat="server" 
     CellPadding="0" 
     CellSpacing="5" 
     RepeatDirection="Vertical">...</asp:Datalist>
```

when i do this in the code-behind:

```
     this.dlSubs.DataSource = dtCat; // dtCat is a datatable with about 13 rows
     this.dlSubs.DataBind();
```

everything gets rendered in one column (vertical)
but i want two colums... so i do this:

```
 DataTable dtCat = shop.DAL.ArtikelenDB.GetLeftMenu(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("catg")));
 double tmpDouble = (double)dtCat.Rows.Count / 2.0;
 double repRow = Math.Ceiling(tmpDouble);
 dlSubs.RepeatColumns = Convert.ToInt32(repRow);
 dlSubs.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical; // also tried without this line...
 this.dlSubs.DataSource = dtCat;
 this.dlSubs.DataBind();
```

but when i do the above. it gets rendered horizontally... how is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it... i had to set the repeatcolumns to 2 instead of manually calculating the rows...
the property name is still repeatCOLUMNS so i should have known that...
when you turn the repeatdirection. it remains columns instead of switching to rows

my bad... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the direction after binding your datasource.

Comment: but the direction is allready set in the .aspx file... i will try it